# 'Object not found' error appeared after trying to knit my r-markdown {R}

Tags: r, function, r-markdown, dplyr, mapply

I was working on a rmarkdown project and my code was working perfectly until I tried to knit. I got the following error:

"Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `number_value`. x object 'index' not found ℹ Input `number_value` is `mapply(get_number, Data_3$value, Data_3$Likert_Scale)`."

I was confused because my code worked perfectly inside each chunk and the error only occurred when I tried to knit. I looked online and found that I should try restarting R-studio and then re-knit the file. After I restarted, my code no longer worked (inside each chunk and when trying to knit). I have no idea what went wrong and how I could fix it.

I will post the code that is causing me problems below. The error says "x object 'index' not found" ('index' is a variable in my function) so I tried initializing it in my function. That did get rid of the error but the resulting values were, "<dbl [1]>". I also tried a different way of applying the function but that resulted in the values being "3".

I am frustrated because my code worked before trying to knit. I would greatly appreciate any help with my issue. Thanks!

```
get_number <- function( value, scale ){
  
  #index = 0
  
  # find indexes where the scale exists
  scale_indexes <- which( Likert_Scales$Likert_Scale %in% scale )
  # find indexes where the response value exists
  response_indexes <- which( Likert_Scales$Response %in% value )
  
  # find where the scale and value indexes are the same
  for( i in scale_indexes ){
    for( j in response_indexes ){
      if( i == j ){
        # get the number value at for the correct index
        index = i
        
      }
    }
  }
  
  # get the number value at for the correct index
  number_value = Likert_Scales$Num_Response[index]
  
  # return number value
  return(number_value)
}

# test function
get_number( "Sometimes", "Likert_PSS_rev")

# apply function to Data_3
Data_4 <- Data_3 %>%
  #mutate( testing = get_number( value, Likert_Scale ) )
  mutate( number_value = mapply( get_number, Data_3$value, Data_3$Likert_Scale ) )
```

Comment: Can you add some data to test this? `dput(Data_3)`, Maybe there exists a better way to write `get_number` function.

Comment: I suspect that previously there was code/variables in your global environment which allowed the chunks to work when run, but not the knit. So don't focus on "it worked before". Focus on what's wrong with your RMarkdown code. It seems that the loop is not returning the object `index`.

Comment: @neilfws My get_number function works on its own, but are you saying I need a "return(index)" inside the loop?

Comment: It's difficult to debug from your example code. But in general, loops are not a good way to return values. The error says `index` is not found, so the loop is not returning it. A loop returns the result of the last run-through so perhaps the result of that is undefined.

Comment: @neilfws Thanks for the insight, I am going to play around with it more. Thanks for helping me out, I really appreciate it.